# Problem with \setmainfont{Gill Sans} in MikTex 2.9

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am trying to use the beamer theme Zurich in Windows7, but when I compile it (I chose Xelatex) I get always the following error:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Gill Sans" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.30 \setmainfont{Gill Sans}
                            ^^I^^I% Beamer ignores "main font" in favor of s...

?
```

Any Idea about how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have Gill Sans?

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle for the quick response. How I can add it ?

Comment: @MedVall Gill Sans is not a free font. If you have it bundled with your OS, fine, otherwise you need to buy it.

Comment: Gill sans can be bought from http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/gill-sans

Comment: You can also try free alternatives: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gill+sans+free+download+windows

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. I installed "Gill Sans Pro", but I still have the same error!. Is there something that I must do after the installation of Gill Sans ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a try at the `Gillius No2` free opentype font, inspired by Gill Sans. It also can be used with `(pdf)latex`, and is available with TeX Live as well as MiKTeX. There is also a `condensed` version.

*Edit:*

Under  MiKTeX, to make the package work with `(pdf)latex`, after installing the package, you should run `updmap` as administrator.

*Added:*

As mentioned by @Harish Kumar, in `beamerfontthemeZurich.sty`, you should comment all the lines concerning `Gill Sans`, and replace, towards the end:

`\newcommand{\handwriting}{\fontspec{augie}}`

with `\newcommand{\handwriting}{\fontspec{Augie}}`.

I give an example of the result below.

As I have both fonts, here is a small test for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gillius2}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gillius ADF No2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\llap{\texttt{Gillius ADF No2: \qquad}}\vskip-\baselineskip\lipsum[11]
\vskip4ex
{\itshape \lipsum[11]}
\vskip4ex
{\bfseries \lipsum[11]}
\vskip 4ex
\fontspec{Gill Sans Std}
\vskip4ex
\llap{\texttt{Gill Sans Std}: \qquad}\vskip-\baselineskip\lipsum[11]
\vskip4ex
{\itshape\lipsum[11]}
\vskip4ex
{\bfseries \lipsum[11]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the result of the `example-talk.tex` file with Zurich theme:

[image]

Comment: How I can modify the zurich theme https://github.com/ppletscher/beamerthemezurich in order to use this font instead of Gill Sans?

Comment: @MedVall Open `beamerfontthemeZurich.sty`, find and comment the lines `\setmainfont{Gill Sans}  % Beamer ignores "main font" in favor of sans font
\setsansfont{Gill Sans}     % This is the font that beamer will use by default
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontspec{Gill Sans}}`. Below you will find many other alternatives like `Linux Libertine`, uncomment those lines as they are included in all distribution. Or add `\usepackage{gillius2}` instead to use Bernard's method.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: There seems to be a problem under MiKTeX with the handwriting font (`augie`).

Comment: @Bernard `augie` works for me in miktex. Is it giving trouble to you? `\ECFAugie` is the one that works.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Problem solved! The reason was in `beamerfontthemeZurich.sty`: the font was named `augie` instead of `Augie`!

Comment: When I compile your example I get the error:
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Gill Sans Std" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.18 \fontspec{Gill Sans Std}

Comment: But do you have the font installed? If you don't, you have to comment that part of the file in order to compile. I just aded it for ccomparison. There are small differences  most notably Gill Sans Std is heavier than Gillius ADF No2.

Comment: @Bernard, I downloaded it from  (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/gillius.zip), then I installed it. Now I have a problem in the command `\fontspec{Gill Sans Std}` which as in your example at the line 18.

Comment: Remove that line: it can work only if you have Gill Sans Std, which is a commercial font.

Comment: @Bernard. That fix the problem!. But for the Zurich theme I got the error: 
**! LaTeX Error: Command \handwriting already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
l.74 \newcommand{\handwriting}{\fontspec{Augie}}**

Comment: You should comment that line in `beamerfontthemeZurich.sty` or replace it. The only problem is that in this file, `Augie` is written `augie`. Or use \ renewcommand in your preamble if you don't want to touch upon that file.

Comment: @Bernard The problem was that I did not have the `Augie` font... It works perfectly now !.

Comment: @Med Vall: Fine! :o)

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to feel useful.